# Ajax for updating page based on server work

Tags: ajax, struts

I have an application that loads data from an outside source. The process takes several hours, and I'd like to continuously update the web page with messages saying something like "data loaded for account name1, data loaded for account name2" etc.. In other words the server is working, and I need to send data about this work from the server to the client without them refreshing the page (or pressing buttons or doing anything else.)

Is AJAX the way to go? Does anyone have a code sample / recommended tutorial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to use a JavaScript `setTimeout` that fires an Ajax request to something on the server side that knows how to track progress. Something as simple as a [`jQuery $.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) would likely be sufficient.

The other option would be to implement some form of push, but I'd think a simple "how's my job doing" request at infrequent intervals would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Do you by any chance have a code example? I'd really appreciate it. Or a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I've never been involved in writing pages that use **websockets** but this *new* technology might be interesting in what you actually want to perform.

consider the following : [websocket.org](http://www.websocket.org/)